# Applying header range fix to apache 2.0.59 issue CVE-2011-3192

Tags: apache-2.2, security, http-headers

I've been trying to apply the suggested fix to apache for CVE-2011-3192 which was to add to httpd.conf

```
# Drop the Range header when more than 5 ranges. 
# CVE-2011-3192 
SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1 
RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range
```

However, in Apache 2.0.59, configtest says

```
Syntax error on line .... 
header unset takes two arguments
```

We still require the use of the range header so to unset the whole range portion is not really an option.  Any thoughts on getting this to work?

Comment: Do you have the headers (mod_headers) mod enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad news!  [mod_headers in 2.0.59](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.0.59/modules/metadata/mod_headers.c) doesn't seem to play nice with environment variables in its validation code.

It parses like this:

`RequestHeader {action} {inhdr} {value} {envclause}`

For `unset`, 2.0.59 validates like this, scrapping a directive if it has a third argument (`value`) after the directive name:

```c
if (new->action == hdr_unset) {
    if (value)
        return "header unset takes two arguments";
}
```

So, `RequestHeader unset Range` works, and `RequestHeader unset Range bytes=0-1000` breaks as intended.. but `RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range` also breaks.

Someone figured that out somewhere along the line, and [current versions](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.2.19/modules/metadata/mod_headers.c) do this, instead - putting the arguments where they belong:

```c
if (new->action == hdr_unset) {
    if (value) {
        if (envclause) {
            return "header unset takes two arguments";
        }
        envclause = value;
        value = NULL;
    }
}
```

So, it's still parsing the `envclause` into the `value` position, but since unset doesn't take a value, it rearranges accordingly.  So, now, `RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range` works, but `RequestHeader unset Range bytes=0-1000 env=bad-range` still throws a validation error.. and `RequestHeader unset Range bytes=0-1000` probably just blows up at runtime.

---

To fix, there's no shortage of bad options - patching then recompiling mod_headers to work correctly is one option, or just flat-out upgrading Apache.  But, it might be worth a shot to empty the header with `set` (no validation bugs), instead of using `unset`:

```
RequestHeader set Range "badrange" env=bad-range
```

On the Apache 2.2 I checked on, junk data in the "Range" field will simply be ignored; in essence, an effective unset.

Comment: Many, many thank for this comprehensive answer.  This issue became a bit of a headache for us and we actually found the best option for us was to use the mod_rangecnt option as presented in the announcement. This curl command is useful for testing to see if a site returns a 206 and maybe vulnerable, or in the case of the a successful mod_rangecnt implementation a 416  "curl -H HEAD -H Range:bytes=5-0,5-1,5-2,5-3,5-4,5-5,5-6,5-7  --dump-header - <hostname>"